# Improving Java ImageIO read/write with PNG that has alpha

Tags: java, image, png

I have a large PNG image (600x600) and my application makes the image opaque and writes out the file. The problem is that the performance with ImageIO is terrible. Are there any other alternatives? I require the image to be opaque. Below is what I am doing:

```
    BufferedImage buf = ImageIO.read(localUrl);
    float[] scales = {1f, 1f, 1f, 1f};  // R, G, B, A
    float[] offsets = {0f, 0f, 0f, 1f};   // R, G, B, A
    RescaleOp rescaler = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);
    BufferedImage opaque = rescaler.filter(buf, null);
    File outputfile = new File(localUrl.getPath());
    ImageIO.write(opaque, "png", outputfile);
```

Comment: Don't know if this will help you. I have an open source Java image library [here](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe) which can read write PNG w/o alpha. By default writing without alpha channel and you can choose compression level for speed.

Comment: Do you have any metrics on saving a alpha based and none alpha based image?

Comment: So I did a quick test using your code on an image of 1600x1440, it took 0.280 seconds to load, 0.183 seconds to resample and 0.784 seconds to write ... I'm not sure I would call any of that terrible...(and my PC is under load ~75% cpu usage BEFORE I ran the test, so yeah, a lot going on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `RescaleOp` isn't entirely necessary here if you just want to get rid of transparency. A simpler solution would be drawing the image on a background like so:

```
Color bgColor = Color.WHITE;

BufferedImage foreground = ImageIO.read(localUrl);
int width = foreground.getWidth();
int height = foreground.getHeight();
BufferedImage background = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = background.createGraphics();
g.setColor(bgColor);
g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
g.drawImage(foreground, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();
File outputfile = new File(localUrl.getPath());
ImageIO.write(background, "png", outputfile);
```

This seems like a simpler method of doing things and would *probably* require less processing power, but I doubt there would be a huge difference. If you're not satisfied with the speed the image can be read / written from the hard drive, there's little you can do to speed that up.

Answer (score 0):

With [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj):

```
private static void removeAlpha(File file1,File file2) {
    PngReaderByte reader = new PngReaderByte(file1);
    ImageInfo info = reader.imgInfo;
    PngWriter writer = new PngWriter(file2,info);
    writer.setFilterPreserve(true);
    writer.setCompLevel(6);
    writer.copyChunksFrom(reader.getChunksList(), ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL_SAFE);
    if( info.bitDepth != 8 ||info.channels!=4) throw new RuntimeException("expected 8bits RGBA ");
    while(reader.hasMoreRows()) {
        ImageLineByte line = reader.readRowByte();
        byte [] buf = line.getScanlineByte();
        for(int i=0,j=3;i<info.cols;i++,j+=4)
            buf[j]=(byte)255;
        writer.writeRow(line);
    }
    reader.end();
    writer.end();
}
```

I'm not sure if this would enhance the perfomance. Bear in mind, also that (contrarily to Parker Hoyes' answer) this simply kills the alpha channel, but it does not blend with some background color (hence the "original" color will appear in the previously-transparent now-opaque regions).